# How do i Optimize/Improve ram while running a massive import into sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I currently am importing a massive database of around 180 million records with roughly 300+ columns. I am sure you are all aware this takes a very long time. I am using sql server on a windows server 2012 machine. The first upload failed at about 38 million. I am on my second try and have been running my server for days with no break. So my question is, even though I am running this import currently, am I able to do anything to reduce the physical memory that is being used?
My system has 24gb of ram and it currently is using 22.5 of that (93-94%). I don't want this upload to fail. The system is a 4 core processor. What can I do?

Comment: *The first upload failed at about 38 million* Upload what? Are you using SSIS, `SqlBulkCopy`, why aren't you backing up and restoring?

Comment: are you not committing once in a while? every 1, 5 or 10 million records for example. there should normally be no physical memory (ram) problem importing large sets of data

Comment: I am using ssis. I amnot backing up and restoring because it is a text file. that i need to load into the database. I did not think i could commit using the import/export wizard.

Comment: See if my answer to [VLDB with large quantity of data file imports](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44054/8783) helps or not. You can do many things to tune your loading process using SSIS. Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: The easy answer via comment is "you don't" SSIS is an in-memory based ETL engine. It will attempt to consume every last nibble of RAM while it's running if it thinks it can use it effectively. There are certainly things you can do to increase/decrease the amount of memory required for a package to transform the data from the source to a destination. You specify you're importing a *database* but you also say it's a file. Which is it? A few jobs back, we'd import 50+ GB files a week so it can handle it but you might need to wok on your design. Need more details to be effective in answering this.